# How to map lottery permutations without repeat to an unique id?

Tags: algorithm

I store a tip of a lottery field of 49 fields with 6 numbers in a bit string like this:
"1011000001010000000000100000000000000000000000000" which represents the numbers 1 3 4 10 12 23.
I've been trying to find the mapping for hours. I know there is one, but I can't find it. It seems so simple.
Is there anyone here who can help me?
In case of 6 out of 49 there are 13.983.816 possibilities.
So:
1111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 = 1
1111101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 = 2
.
.
.
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111 = 13.983.816

Comment: Could you clearify what you mean saying "mapping"? And could you show your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: For now I've just wasted a lot of paper, as I tried to find the correlations between the combinations in bit representation and id.

Comment: @Hoppi are you sure your bit string and numbers are correct? Just asking because if you turned each 1 in the bitstring into it's index you get 0, 3, 4, 9, 11, 22, which is almost what you have except for some one-off errors.

Comment: @Primusa You're right. I'm correcting it. But I started from index 1.

Comment: What is the maximum number that can be met? 23? Or are there exactly 6 numbers of 1 to 49? I don't know much about lotteries, maybe that's why I can't find the logic behind "13 983 816 possibilities" and your string representation.

Comment: Can you use non-consecutive IDs? In this case you would be just able to convert this bit mask to a base-10 64-bit integer (`long`) and store it this way. Like `1111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` is `554153860399104` and `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111` is `63`. This would be unique indeed, but unsorted and non-consecutive.

Comment: Otherwise, this two articles can be helpful to you if you find a way to implement it. Get ID by combination - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363239/fast-way-to-get-a-position-of-combination-without-repetitions and get combination by ID - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368526/fast-way-to-get-a-combination-given-its-position-in-reverse-lexicographic-or

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. There's plenty I'll have to check tomorrow what works and I'll update you then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your number from a list of input values, perform the following

```
value := 0
for i from 0..5:
   value := value + 2 ** (49 - list[i])
```

-where `**` denotes exponentiation.

Unpacking can be accomplished by either iterating over the bitstring collecting the indices of set bits, or from taking the floored log base 2 of the value and removing the leading '1' repeatedly:

```
for i from 0..5
    list[i] := 49 - floor(log2(value))
    value := value - 2 ** (49 - list[i])
```

However, you can do much better in terms of compression / packing. For an equally fast (probably faster) to unpack format, consider converting each number to a 6-bit bitstring, and then concatenating the results. This gives us 36 digits instead of the 49 required by your solution. Implementation:

```
value := 0
for i from 0..5
    value := (value << 6) + list[i]
```

Unpacking is very efficient in this case, as you just mask off all but the last 6 bits with an `& 0x3f` and then a right bitshift `>> 6` repeatedly.

```
for i from 5..0
    list[i] := value & 0x3f
    value := value >> 6
```

While more efficient, we can still do a bit better, at a slight cost of speed. If we instead represent these values as a single base-49 number, we avoid wasting any bits at all.

```
value := 0
for i from 0..5
    value := value * 49 + list[i]
```

However unpacking is a bit more expensive

```
for i from 5..0
    list[i] := value % 49
    value := floor(value / 49)
```

This approach requires 34 bits, rather than the previous 36.

Comment: Thanks. I hoped to get the indexes below the maximum of an unsigned integer, but that was not to be. So your solution is still the best that I could apply.

Comment: @Hoppi it is actually possible. I found a way to accomplish 24 bit packing after posting this, but it was too buggy to include in this answer, and I assumed someone else would mention it in their answer.

Comment: @Hoppi if we always represent the numbers in ascending order `a_k` must be larger than `a_(k-1)`. This can be used to shrink the number of valid combinations drastically, but its tricky to implement the mapping.

Comment: @Hoppi just created a second answer using said algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach based on the math.stackexchange links provided in the comments section. This method takes advantage of the fact that we are storing combinations, not permutations, so we can eliminate redundant representations of the same tuple. In fact, this approach brings the compression down to a mere 24 bits.

I wrote this algorithm out in Python rather than psuedo-code because I did not feel confident in giving you an algorithm this finicky without running it first. I also spent some time optimizing this solution (without sacrificing readability), so it will still handle large volumes of inputs fairly well if need be. However, if it does become a bottleneck you can always consider one of the simpler and cheaper alternatives in my original answer.

```py
from functools import reduce
from math import factorial

def ncr(n, r):
    if r > n: return 0
    r = min(r, n-r)
    result = reduce(int.__mul__, range(n, n-r, -1), 1)
    return result // factorial(r)

def encode(numbers):
    return sum(ncr(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(numbers, 1))

def decode(value, n=50, r=6, y=ncr(50,6)):
    if not n: return (0,) if r else tuple()
    if y <= value:
        return decode(value - y, n - 1, r - 1, y * r // n) + (n,)
    return decode(value, n - 1, r, y * (n - r) // n)
```

Do note however, that I use the range `[0, 49)`, so you may need to offset everything by one if you plan to use 1-based indexing like your post shows.

To test it-

```py
from itertools import combinations
def test_all():
    numbers = list(range(0,49))
    for comb in combinations(numbers, 6):
        if comb != decode(encode(comb)):
            print("error", comb, encode(comb), decode(encode(comb)))
```

Comment: Looks good but for code comments. Does run time change with `@functools.lru_cache()`ing n-choose-r?

Comment: @greybeard I'm doubtful that caching `ncr` would make of a difference as the code stands now- when I profiled it `ncr` consumed about 0.299045s total, `encode` 0.82748s, and `decode` 2.57875s. Decode itself could probably be sped up by implementing an iterative version, and if rewritten into `ncr` calls, then maybe a cached `ncr` would be faster than the divide + multiply.